# which is better tls or ssl?

Tags: php, security, smtp, websecurity

recently I learned about phpmailer and I wonder which one should I use as SMTPSecure, tls or ssl ?
According to some articles, https needs a ssl certificate whereas it is written in Wikipedia that ssl has been deprecated.

Comment: tls is the current standard ssl is legacy

Comment: you still buy\install a ssl certificate.

Answer (score 3):

To be precise SSL (SSLv1, SSLv2 and SSLv3) is dead, technically (hopefully) only TLS is used today.

However people still stick to the term "SSL" even if it is now incorrect. I assume this is because all the non-technical people who learned that SSL means secure. A new term like TLS will just confuse those people.

Conclusion: Nowadays SSL is more or less a synonym of TLS (unless you specify an exact version like SSLv3 or TLSv1.2).

BTW: As far as I know as TLS was developed they decided to change the name from SSLv4 to TLSv1. May be because SSL was a proprietary protocol developed by Netscape and TLS is an open protocol developed by many people under the lead of the IETF.

Comment: Thank you Robert..! This was insightful.

Answer (score 1):

TLs and SSL both are protocols. SSL is an older version and TLS is a newer version of SSL. Currently, the latest version of [TLs is 1.3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) which has recently released.

I hope this resource will help you to [secure email server](https://www.clickssl.net/blog/how-ssl-secure-your-mail-server).

Comment: Thank you Dana..! This was insightful.

Answer (score 1):

TLS is the name of newer versions of the SSLprotocol.

**But in the case of SMTP (and other protocol) "SSL" means SMTP over TLS while "TLS" means SMTP with the STARTTLS command.** See [RFC 3207](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3207).

Both SSL the protocol and SSL as SMTP over TLS are deprecated.

Comment: Thank you Erwan..! This was insightful.